# linking parent page link to anchor in an iframe

Tags: html, iframe, anchor

I've been searching and searching, but I'm absolutely stumped on this: I have an index.html page that has a few iframes in in- 100% width and height stacked atop one another. The index has fixed navigation with a z-index OVER the frames. My index has scrolling basically disabled with javascript.

So I'm trying to have the navigation (which is on the index page) link to specific anchors inside one of the iframes, which will load in that iframe. I've obviously gathered this is easier said then done. Why `<a href="iframe-src.html#anchor" target="iframe">` doesn't work eludes me, but apparently it doesn't.

What's the work-around for this? Here's how my index is basically set up:

```
    <html>
    <head>

    ** some CSS and Javascript here that I know's irrelevant. **

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';  // firefox, chrome
        document.body.scroll = "no";    // ie only
        document.documentElement.style.overflowX = 'hidden';     // horizontal scrollbar will be hidden
        document.documentElement.style.overflowY = 'hidden';     // vertical scrollbar will be hidden
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="landing.html" name="landing" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0;"></iframe>   
<iframe src="work1.html" name="work-iframe" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1;"></iframe>
<iframe src="info.html" name="info" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 4;"></iframe>

<nav>   
    <a href="work.html#parker" target="work-iframe">PARKER BROTHERS CLASSICS</a>

    <a href="work.html#bohs" target="work-iframe">BOHS & HONS</a>

    <a href="work.html#companion" target="work-iframe">THE COMPANION SERIES</a>

    <a href="work.html#balmer" target="work-iframe">BALMER</a>

    <a href="work.html#hoeweler" target="work-iframe">MICHAEL HOEWELER</a>

    <a href="work.html#ampugreen" target="work-iframe">AMPUGREEN</a>

    <a href="work.html#occasional" target="work-iframe">OCCASIONAL SYMPHONY</a>

    <a href="work.html#type" target="work-iframe">TYPE & LOGOS</a>

    <a href="work.html#nextwave" target="work-iframe">NEXT WAVE FESTIVAL</a>

    <a href="work.html#illustration" target="work-iframe">ILLUSTRATIONS</a>

    <a href="work.html#stationnorth" target="work-iframe">STATION NORTH</a>
</nav>
```

thoughts?

Comment: You have been [searching](https://www.google.be/search?q=linking+to+an+anchor+in+an+iframe) ?

Comment: Just a note: your `<nav>` links all have `href="work.html#somelink"`, but your `<iframe>` has `src="work1.html"` - note the added `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using pure JavaScript and no libraries, I'm just going to explain how you could go about doing it instead of using code (since it's only one possible solution out of many).

You may want to move your JS to the window.load function unless you will always expect your site visitors to be using JavaScript.

Hide all iframes except one (the first? whatever you choose to be the default iframe).

Add event handlers (onclick perhaps) to your nav hyperlinks to do a few things:
1. toggle the visibility (and hide the currently visible) iframe related to the certain nav item, if necessary (depending on which is clicked)
2. Detect the offset from the iframe's specific anchor to the top of the iframe's page using (pseudocode) iframe.ELEMENT.offsetTop in order to use...
3. ... iframe.ELEMENT.scrollTo(value_determined_in_step_2)

I *believe* this will work for your particular use case as described.